# SQLite count ocurrences in row

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

Imagine I have a column of a table like this:

```
b
-
1
1
1
2
3
```

and I want to obtain

```
a | b
-----
1 | 3
2 | 1
3 | 1
```

representing the ocurrencies for that row. I have read that this would do the job:

```
select b, count(b) from table group by b
```

how ever, the result I get is just this:

```
3 | 5
```

What's wrong?

Comment: almost fine :-) just missing table name

Comment: "table" was supposed to be the name of the table in the example. I tried that query in code, and through command line (adb shell -> sqlite3 ... -> select ...)

Comment: I tried that calling the table X and it works as expected. As TABLE is a keyword, I don't think it is a good idea to call a table "table".

Comment: no, its only in the example here in stackoverflow, in my code has other names. Ill try again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned the SQL appears fine.  I ran a quick test here with the following:

```
create table #temp
(num int)

insert #temp
select 1 union all
select 1 union all
select 1 union all
select 2 union all
select 3 

select Num, COUNT(num) as Occurances from #temp group by num

drop table #temp
```

This gives the below result set:

```
Num Occurances
1       3
2       1
3       1
```

Compare the above to your whole code, including the table creation etc.

Comment: ok, i was using "order by" instead of "group by"..... That's the benefit of copy&paste in the code.... Thanks!